# Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: windows, gcc, gtk, msys2

I've installed MSYS2 on Windows 7 and I have successfully executed

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```

(the above as per **Step 2** of [Setting up GTK for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/)) and

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain base-devel
```

but when I try to compile the [hello world](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) with

```
gcc -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
```

I get the following

```
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
bash: gcc: command not found
```

If I try from MinGW 64-bit shell the output is

```
MyHome@MyHome-PC MINGW64 ~
$ gcc -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've also checked that

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the above as per Step 2 of Setting up GTK for Windows

They seem to have some **outdated instructions** on their site.

I actually have had to setup the [following package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4)

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4
```

### A couple of possible runtime issues

Then I could compile the example but it is not running fine. I still get a runtime error:

```
---------------------------
hello-world-gtk.exe - Errore di sistema
---------------------------
Impossibile avviare il programma perché libgio-2.0-0.dll non è presente nel computer. Per risolvere il problema, provare a reinstallare il programma.
```

Looking at [this issue](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3794) I've tried adding `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to my sys `PATH`: it does not show the runtime error but the exe is really not working anyway (the app does not show up as expected).

AFAICS  `gtk4-demo-application` itself is not running fine on my Windows, so finally I've had to revert to GTK3 and I compiled the example the [GTK3 getting started](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html)

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-1 example-1.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

and the above *compiles and runs* fine.

### Solution of the runtime issue

Otherwise, there is the option to [build GTK4 on Windows from source](https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2021/03/18/build-and-run-gtk-4-applications-with-visual-studio/) *without MSYS2*.

It is very important this note

> It works out of the box on my VirtualBox machine, however on my physical PC with an intel GPU, I get a crash at startup:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5211345E (ig4icd32.dll) in gtk4-demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000050
```

> This can be worked around by using cairo rendering:

```
C:\src\gtk>set GSK_RENDERER=cairo
C:\src\gtk>C:\gnome\bin\gtk4-demo.exe
```

### Conclusion: procedure for GTK4 on MSYS2

In conclusion `set GSK_RENDERER=cairo` is the same fix that *does the trick also to run the executable compiled under MSYS2*, therefore the final solution consists of

- installing `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4`
- adding `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;` in the start of the `PATH` system environment variable
- adding a new `GSK_RENDERER` system environment variable with value `cairo`
- use the MSYS2 MinGW 64 bit shell to compile (as GTK4) and run the exe